# Associative array to string conversion

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, associative-array

I had a look at a number of related answers for this question but couldn't find one that applies to this case.

```
$DatabaseConfig = array('DB_TYPE' => 'MySQL',
                        'DB_HOST' => 'localhost',
                        'DB_NAME' => 'simpleCMS',
                        'DB_USER' => 'root',
                        'DB_PASS' => 'mypass');

$dsn = $this->DatabaseConfig['DB_TYPE'].':host='.$this->DatabaseConfig['DB_HOST'].';dbname='.$this->DatabaseConfig;
```

I'm getting a `Notice: Array to string conversion` and the there's no connection.
Everything works fine when I insert the parameters manually.

How would I convert the key values into strings in this case? I tried placing `(string)` in various places but no luck.
Also, slightly unrelated, but if someone has any thoughts on making this `$dsn` a little less verbose? I couldn't find a cleaner design.

**EDIT**
Thank you everyone pointing out I was just missing the last parameter. The `Notice: Array to string conversion` is no longer visible.
I am however, presented with a new fatal error:
`Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOException::query()`
And PDOException:
`exception 'PDOException' with message 'could not find driver'`

But again, when I enter the parameters manually, the connection works fine.
Why is the `$dsn` in it's current format not accepted?

Comment: perhaps you meant to do `$this->DatabaseConfig = array(...);`

Comment: You need, at the end, `';dbname='.$this->DatabaseConfig['DB_NAME']`.  (You're missing the `['DB_NAME']`at the end.)

Comment: After your update, you need to post more code.  You have somehow called `query()` on the exception caught from a PDO failure.  Post the code where your connection is established, and where you call `query()`.

Comment: Oh, I don't know if PDO drivers are case sensitive. Make it lowercase...  `'DB_TYPE' => 'mysql',`

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski `'DB_TYPE' => 'mysql'` works. You might want to add it to your answer and I'll accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDO driver names are apparently case sensitive. Use `mysql` instead of `MySQL`

```
$DatabaseConfig = array('DB_TYPE' => 'mysql',
                        'DB_HOST' => 'localhost',
                        'DB_NAME' => 'simpleCMS',
                        'DB_USER' => 'root',
                        'DB_PASS' => 'mypass');
```

As additional cause for concern, this error message implies you have tried to call `query()` on an object which is actually a `PDOException`. Your `try/catch` logic wherein you establish the PDO object warrants additional attention, though you have not posted it.  Verify that the variable you're storing the PDO object in doesn't somewhere get reused by the exception handling...

> Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDOException::query()

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you provided, below is how to access the array.  Not sure why you are using object notation?

`$DatabaseConfig = array('DB_TYPE' => 'MySQL',
                        'DB_HOST' => 'localhost',
                        'DB_NAME' => 'simpleCMS',
                        'DB_USER' => 'root',
                        'DB_PASS' => 'mypass');`

`$dsn = $DatabaseConfig['DB_TYPE'].':host='.$DatabaseConfig['DB_HOST'].';dbname='.$DatabaseConfig**['DB_NAME']**;`

(you were missing the DB_NAME key)

But, you also had an issue in your original script with ';dbname='.$DatabaseConfig;

Notice you didn't specify an array key to access.  You only specified $DatabaseConfig.  This is where the error "Array to string" occurs.

Comment: The object notation is assumed to be due to trimmed code, where this appears in an object method somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your final setting seems to be missing ($this->DatabaseConfig['DB_NAME']):

```
$DatabaseConfig = array('DB_TYPE' => 'MySQL',
                    'DB_HOST' => 'localhost',
                    'DB_NAME' => 'simpleCMS',
                    'DB_USER' => 'root',
                    'DB_PASS' => 'mypass');

$dsn = $this->DatabaseConfig['DB_TYPE'].':host='.$this->DatabaseConfig['DB_HOST'].';
dbname='.$this->DatabaseConfig['DB_NAME'];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dsn = $this->{DatabaseConfig}['DB_TYPE'].':host='.$this->{DatabaseConfig}['DB_HOST'].';dbname='.$this->{DatabaseConfig};
```